# Jquery Ajax and Scriptaculous Form Validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, scriptaculous

I have a form that is using scriptaculous form validation but i am using jquery ajax.  The form validation works fine before i add the ajax.  Once i add the ajax it is like the form no longer validates.  The ajax just sumbits the form with no validation.  It is like the validation is just bypassed by the ajax.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery('form').delay(3000).submit(function() {
      string = jQuery("form").serializeArray();

      jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../script_insert.php",
    data: string,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html){
      jQuery('#Right_Content').hide().html(html).fadeIn("slow");;

       }
       })
       return false;
       });
       </script>
```

But when i remove the ajax from the page all together it works fine.  The page validates.  Can anyone tell me how to make sure the form validation takes place before the ajax submit.  I tried the jquery delay but this does not work either.  Thanks.

Comment: Fyi, you only need to write the long `jQuery` once: `(function($){ /* your code */ })(jQuery);` - inside that function you put your code and use `$` instead. If you *need* `$` to access e.g. Prototype, you could at least use `$j` for jQuery - still more readable and less to write.

Comment: Thanks.  First time i have used jquery and scriptaculous together so still learning the rules around the conflict.  Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion: Throw away prototype/scriptaculous. Pretty much everything you can imagine is also available for jQuery. For validation there's http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ for example.

Comment: @ThiefMaster the only reason i didn't use bassistance was because i coldn't get it to validate on blur.  Do you know how to get it to validate on blur and not just on submit?  I would love to keep everything jquery.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add validation as the first thing that `.submit()` does? That way you're sure the form is validated no matter how many form fields have had focus.

```
jQuery('form').submit(function() {
    if (validate()) {
        string = jQuery("form").serializeArray();
        ...
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to prevent further errors, I would recommend you to use absolute paths for the submissions. Instead of `url="../script_insert.php"` use the full path `"url="http://www.yoursite.com/script_insert.php"`

---

2.It sounds like there is no "prevent default" in your script. There are two things you have to do: clear the inputs and the divs that display the errors before loading them!

---

Number 2: you could replace the ajax submit with a jQuery submission placed in a

```
`"$(document).ready(function(){
$('#your_form').submit(function(){
$.post("http://your_site.com/script_insert.php",{ first_variable:$('#first_input_field').val(),second_variable:$('#second_input_field').val(),rand:Math.random()},function(data){
if(data=='yes'){do something}
if(data=='no'){do something else}});
return false;});
});
    });'
```

And in your PHP validation, if the input is correct and the form is valid, do echo "yes" and echo "no" otherwise. Or any other words you want. This also allows for greater flexibility. Edit the above to suit your needs. Add variables as you want and this way everything will be jQuery. If you want to see a valid example, send me a private message and I will show you exactly how it works. With the above code, I've never had any problems whatsoever. And as far as I can tell, jQuery also sanitizes the inputs automatically before sending the post request, which offers you some form of security.